# regular expression - function body extracting

Tags: python, regex

in Python script, for every method definition in some C++ code of the form:

```
return_value ClassName::MethodName(args)
{MehodBody}
```

I need to extract  three parts: the class name, the method name and the method body for further processing. Finding and extracting the ClassName and MethodName is easy, but is there any simple way to extract the body of the method? With all possible `'{'` and `'}'` inside it? Or are regexes unsuitable for such task?

Comment: I will check if I can simply split it on the method header: "return_value ClassName::MethodName(args){" while still getting the ClassName and MethodName strings and somehow linking them to following split result ("method body") because they are vital to what I want to do with the function body. ( otherwise I would simply use re.split ).  Sorry if I'm doing and talking some BS from a point of view of Python guru ;), but I'm totally new to this language and simply want my task done :).

Comment: post your code, and some real input string.

Comment: Ok, I read the split function doc more thoroughly and it seems it does what I want ( RTFM first, you fool! ;) ). Nonetheless thanks for help to all of you. I think that case is closed ( I would do the Horatio Cane thing, but I don't have sunglasses ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = """return_value ClassName::MethodName(args)
{MehodBody {} } """
>>> re.findall(r'\b(\w+)::(\w+)\([^{]+\{(.+)}', s, re.S)
[('ClassName', 'MethodName', 'MehodBody {} ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the [parser module](http://docs.python.org/library/parser.html) rather than regexps since it will handle things like multiple line functions, different indentations and will abort on malformed input so that you can manage things better. "Avoid regexps if you can" is one of the rules I live by since they're often more trouble that they're worth.

---

**Edit:**
Oh okay. I misread your question. I thought you wanted to parse Python code itself. I googled a little bit and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/) but it's C only. Perhaps you can extend that? The grammar for C++ is there in the "C++ programming language book"